# During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I upload Dockerrun.aws.json to Elastic Beanstalk, I get the following errors in EB.

On events:

```
- During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
- Failed to deploy application.
- Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'. Aborting the operation.
```

On Health:

```
Overall:
- Command failed on all instances. 
- Incorrect application version found on all instances. Expected version "Sample Application" (deployment 1).
i-XXXXXXXXXXXX:
- Application deployment failed at 2020-06-13T11:21:07Z with exit status 1 and error: Engine execution has encountered an error.
- Incorrect application version "43" (deployment 5). Expected version "Sample Application" (deployment 1).
```

On Logs:

```
Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete XXXXXXXXXXXX (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "try-new-new",
    "Key": ".docker/config.json"
  },
  "Image": {
    "Name": "registry.gitlab.com/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "80"
    }
  ]
}
```

My .docker/config.json file:

```
{
 "auths" :
 {
    "https://registry.gitlab.com/" :
   {
      "auth" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "email" : "abc@abc.com"
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: In the console, view the logs for your environment. Look at `/var/log/eb-engine.log` and it will probably have some more information about what error you are encountering.

Comment: I added them above with the title "On Logs"

Comment: That error above is actually expected -- there were no other errors at the end of the `eb-engine.log` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the problem is an Authentication problem. Unfortunately, I was unable to authorize AWS to pull the container from Registry.gitlab.com.

For now (though not a complete solution) I have created a solution by moving my container to the AWS Elastic Container Repository.